# How can I execute SQL Statements in a Azure Synapse managed SQL-Pool from Linux command line?

Tags: sql-server, linux, azure-synapse, sqlcmd

I would like to know if there is a simple way to execute SQL Commands on an Azure Synapse managed SQL-Pool from Linux command line?
In my On-Prem Linux setup I'm using *sqlcmd* with Kerberos authentication to simulate the Active Directory login against my On-Prem SQL-Server database.
My question is, Can I also use Kerberos (and the -G option in sqlcmd) to connect to my Azure Synapse managed SQL-Pool database?
if so, How can I do the setup for that?

Thanks a lot in advance.
Regards,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

No.  Synapse does not support Kerberos.  It supports SQL Auth and Azure Active Directory auth.